# replace из списка

Tags: python, list, replace

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать `replace` значения из списка?

Пример:

```
.replace("/video/" + (0-9) + ".mp4", "/video.mp4")
```

Название видео может изменяться, для теста хотелось бы избавиться от цифр внутри ссылки.

исходные -

```
https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/4.mp4
https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/9.mp4
https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/2.mp4
```

желаемый результат -

```
https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/.mp4
```

Comment: что значит "из листа" ? по-русски это называется "список". про какой список речь?

Comment: в примере видно, что у меня после видео есть цифры, из которых можно сделать список

Comment: Приведите пример исходной строки и результата.

Comment: исходная - https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/4.mp4


результат - https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, через регулярки:

```
import re


items = [
    "https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/4.mp4",
    "https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/9.mp4",
    "https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/2.mp4"
]

new_items = [
    re.sub(r'\d+\.mp4', '.mp4', x) for x in items
]
print(new_items)
# ['https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/.mp4', 
#  'https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/.mp4', 
#  'https:/example.com/animated_banners/video/.mp4']
```

---

Если нужно поменять так, чтобы в конце просто было `.mp4`, то можно через `rsplit`:

```
new_items = [
    x.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[0] + '/.mp4' for x in items
]
print(new_items)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло